# Tkinter error in callback - number of arguments

Tags: python, tkinter

Working on a callback function that gives the result of one combo box to another. Stuck at the simpler version of the code. Is it structured wrong or am I not understanding OOP properly? full traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Tim\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1705, in call return self.func(*args) TypeError: on_field_change() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

```
def main():
    # Create the entire GUI program
    program = Converter()
    # Start the GUI event loop
    program.window.mainloop()
        
#class Converter(tk.Tk):  # opens two windows, one odd

class Converter():     
    def __init__(self): 
        #super().__init__()   # is this needed?
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("800x200+10+10")
        self.window.title("Unit Conversion App") 
        self.CreateWidgets()
        self.comboBox_contents = tk.StringVar()
        #self.on_field_change()  # doesn't appear to need to be initiated
        
    def on_field_change(self):  # should go here or outside class declaration?
        print( "combobox updated to ", self.c1.get() ) # does print the updated values
        self.choice_label.configure(text=self.c1.get() )
        self.choice_label.update() #REQUIRED OR ABOVE LINE NEVER SHOWS
        #self.c2.set(self.c1.get)  
        
        
    def CreateWidgets(self):
        v=tk.StringVar()
        self.c1 = ttk.Combobox(self.window, textvar='Box 1',width=30, values=["Mass", "Distance", "Volume"])
        self.c1.set('Click Arrow to choose Property')
        self.c1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.c1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.on_field_change)
        #self.increment_button['command'] = self.increment_counter
        self.c2 = ttk.Combobox(self.window, textvar='Box 2', width=30,values=["Inch", "Foot", "Mile"])
        self.c2.set('Click to choose Source Unit')
        self.c2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        
        self.c3 = ttk.Combobox(self.window, textvar='Box 3', width=30, values=["Inch", "Feet", "Mile"])
        self.c3.set('Click to choose Target Unit')
        self.c3.grid(row=1, column=2)
        
        self.choice_label = ttk.Label(self.window,text="Unit Chosen" ) 
            #the_choice_label = c1.cget("text")
        self.choice_label_text= self.c1.get
            #the_choice_label.update()  # does not update
            #choice_label = Label(text= v ) #does not update
        self.choice_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
             
        self.quit_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text="Quit")
        self.quit_button.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.quit_button['command'] = self.window.destroy 
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Please provide the code for the `on_field_change` method and the code that calls it.

Comment: It should be `def on_field_change(self,event)`

Comment: Mike, code now available. Had some trouble posting.

Comment: Thanks much, @Cool Cloud, worked well. Next problem: I uncommented the last line of the on_field_change  function definition but instead of transferring the choice text to combobox2, the text in the combobox reads:<bound method Entry.get of <tkinter.ttk.Combob"  Rest of line is chopped but something is amis!

Comment: Ive added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a close look and found out the issues you were pointing out:

- You need to pass `event` as an parameter whenever you `bind` to a widget. So your line would change to:

```
def on_field_change(self, event):
....
```

- Then next is, this line should have `()`, like:

```
self.c2.set(self.c1.get())
```

- Also I recommend adding an option, `state='readonly'`, for all your combobox, so the user cant edit the box, like:

```
self.c2 = ttk.Combobox(self.window, textvar='Box 2', width=30, values=["Inch", "Foot", "Mile"],state='readonly')
```

- Furthermore, you can say `event=None` so that you can call the function elsewhere without passing in any argument.

Comment: Thanks again-works as designed. Now I will of course change things to add a way to relate selected units to a conversion factor  and an event handler to do a unit conversion when clicked! I suspect I will post here again.

Answer (score 0):

Function that are bound to an event need to have an event argument. ( `self.c1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.on_field_change)`)

Change you function prototype to:

```
def on_field_change(self,event:tk.Event):
```

event is a `tk.Event` that transports information relative to the event that triggered your function. See here for the event description:
https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: `event:tk.Event` is not necessary, just `event` is fine

Comment: Agreed but type annotation is of great help if your editor supports it and it makes the code more explicit about what is the type of the event received. . Since stack overflow is about helping I do not see a reason to not add it.